# ffmpeg Merge videos removing audio Error:setsar has a unconnected output

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using below command to merge videos removing audio-

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200501-WA0000.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/g3cm1tt7qtd41.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 /storage/emulated/0/Movies/merge_video10.mp4
```

but the command fails with below error-

> FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the
>   FFmpeg developers
>                                                                                           built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>                                                                                           configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>                                                                                           libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>                                                                                           libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>                                                                                           libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>                                                                                           libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>                                                                                           libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>                                                                                           libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>                                                                                           libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>                                                                                           libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>                                                                                         Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
>   Video/VID-20200501-WA0000.mp4':
>                                                                                           Metadata:
>                                                                                             major_brand     : isom
>                                                                                             minor_version   : 512
>                                                                                             compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>                                                                                             encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
>                                                                                           Duration: 00:00:09.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 809 kb/s
>                                                                                             Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 /
>   0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x600, 737 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr,
>   15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
>                                                                                             Metadata:
>                                                                                               handler_name    : VideoHandler
>                                                                                             Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz,
>   stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
>                                                                                             Metadata:
>                                                                                               handler_name    : SoundHandler
>                                                                                         Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Download/g3cm1tt7qtd41.mp4':
>                                                                                           Metadata:
>                                                                                             major_brand     : iso6
>                                                                                             minor_version   : 1
>                                                                                             compatible_brands: mp42iso6avc1isom
>                                                                                             creation_time   : 2020-01-30 11:13:07
>                                                                                           Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.042667, bitrate: N/A
>                                                                                             Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
>   854x480 [SAR 2136:2135 DAR 89:50], 1225 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360
>   tbn, 60 tbc (default)
>                                                                                             Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz,
>   stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
>                                                                                         Filter setsar has a unconnected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concat the filtered streams, not the source streams, so change the input labels i.e.

`[v0] [v1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0`

Add `-an` to remove audio.

Comment: I tried that and with that command doesn't fails but it doesn't remove the audio from output video- `[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0`